# How can I use SASS pre-processor in my Vue components?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, sass

I want to use `language="sass"` in my Vue 2 CLI project's components, but it throws me and error when using SASS syntax:

```
Syntax Error: Missed semicolon
```

I have installed `sass-loader` and `node-sass` as dev dependencies. 
I added this to my webpack config's rules, but that did not fix it either:

```
{
    test: /\.sass$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          indentedSyntax: true,
          // sass-loader version >= 8
          sassOptions: {
            indentedSyntax: true
          },
          prependData: `@import "@/styles/_variables.sass"`
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The SASS code in my component:

```
<style language="sass">

  #app
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
    text-align: center
    color: #2c3e50
    margin-top: 60px

</style>
```

Comment: also attached the sass code you are having

Comment: i added the sass code, but i think it's irrelevant

Comment: The code above looks okay to me. Are you sure you are getting this error from this particular file

Comment: Try removing this code and see that if the error still exist

Comment: When I remove the code or when I add semicolons or use regular CSS inside the `style` tag, it does not throw the error

Comment: Try removing this ```prependData: '@import "@/styles/_variables.sass"'``` from your webpack config file

Comment: that does not solve it either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I repeated the same steps in my vue utils file, and it solved the problem